# How to make full text search in PostgreSQL to search any order of words in the input search_text and also if there are words between them

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to use Django full-text search but I'm having a problem:
I've followed this [documentation](https://www.netlandish.com/blog/2020/06/22/full-text-search-django-postgresql/), and it works quite well. But my problem is that I don't want the postgress to consider the order or permutation of the words I search.
I mean I want the result of searching "good boy" and "boy good" to be the same.
and also when I search "good boy" I want to see the "good bad boy" in the results.
But none of these happen and I can't query "good bad boy" with typing "boy good" or even "good boy" (Because of the "bad" missing).
I've tried to split `search_text` by space and then & the search queries like this in order to remove the order of words but it didn't work.

I changed this code:

```
search_query = SearchQuery(
    search_text
)
search_rank = SearchRank(search_vectors, search_query)
```

to this:

```
s = SearchQuery(search_text.split(' ')[0])
for x in search_text.split(' ')[1:]:
    s = s & SearchQuery(x)
search_query = s
search_rank = SearchRank(search_vectors, search_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this quite easily in PostgreSQL.
I suggest reading carefully the documentation on [Basic Text Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-MATCHING).

What you need is to use `<->`, (FOLLOWED BY) tsquery operator.
If you use an integer instead of `-` you can express the desired proximity :

> <N>, where N is an integer standing for the difference between the positions of the matching lexemes.

So you should find a way to make Python to execute this PostgreSQL function:
`to_tsquery('good <1> boy | boy <1> good' );`.

Maybe just calling `SearchQuery` with the string `'good <1> boy | boy <1> good'` just works, but you should refer to the tutorial documentation to find how to use `<->` with the method `SearchQuery`.

Edited after comment.

Looking at `Django` [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ece18207cbb64dd89014e279ac636a6c9829828e/django/contrib/postgres/search.py#L130) you can see that the constructor for `SearchQuery` class pass a default parameter `search_type='plain'`.

You can pass a different parameter to implement a different kind of search.
In the Django project [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/), you can find one example for each accepted string value for the named parameter `search_type`: 'plain', 'phrase', 'raw',  'websearch'.

If you pass `search_type=raw` you can provide a formatted search query with terms and operators, but I'm not sure if Django supports the `<Ineger>` operator as I said before you should try it.

Have you tried a search with `search_type='raw'`, and a value of `"'good <1> boy | boy <1> good'"`?

If the FOLLOWED BY operator (`<->`) is not supported the close you can get to what you wanted is calling `SearchQuery` with `search_type='phrase'`.

This will find both `good boy` and `boy good` but the exact behaviour depends on the definition of the stop words used by the [Dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS) set for PostgreSQL.

Comment: I know that progress has this. My question is how to do this with Django's ORM

Comment: @K47 I edited my answer, I could not know what you already know, pointing out what Django is using under the hood is a way to help you in solving your problem. I read some Django documentation to find some detail on how Full Text Search it is implemented and I added some suggestion, I did not post a solution to your problem but what I think is valid approach to the problem, I hope this can help.